# Blank preview in visual editor android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout

I have created a new project in android studio using the basic layout. This is what is happening in both content_main and activity_main: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHsnc.jpg

Also note: I have not modified any code.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening if there is a error in your layout or class and is not successfully initiated .

Build->Make Project

Or

Build-> Reduild Project

If error is still there than you have to invalidate cache and restart android studio.

Comment: Force refresh your layout and if you are using the api level 28 alpha, plz downgrade it with 27 and try.